# Sumifs returns 0 if an affected cell is updated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have spreadsheet that I've been making for budgeting which involves updating a total value based on dates in relation to another spreadsheet.

I have a formula that's been working but I found an issue where values aren't being added if a cell above gets updated.

Formula for the cell holding the total (in Bar!B4):

```
=SUMIFS(Foo!A:A,IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C,Foo!D:D),">="&Bar!A4, IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C, Foo!D:D),"<"&Bar!A5)
```

With:

- Foo!A:A

  - The currency value
- Foo!C:C

  - The date that the item needs to be paid by
- Foo!D:D

  - The date that the item was paid by (if applicable)
- Bar!A4 and A5

  - The date range

Taking this as sample data for table Foo (all values fudged):

```
A        B  C           D
Amount      Due         Paid
$200.00     2017-03-01  2017-01-03
$40         2017-03-12  2017-03-03
$300.00     2017-04-01
$40         2017-04-12
```

And this as the result in Bar:

```
A          B
Date       Total
2017-02-30 $240
2017-03-15 $0
2017-03-30 $340
2017-04-15 $0
```

If I update cell Foo!D4 it have a date in between the ranges of Bar!A3 and Bar!A4, the formula does not register the value in Foo!A5.

Table Foo after update:

```
A        B  C           D
Amount      Due         Paid
$200.00     2017-03-01  2017-01-03
$40         2017-03-12  2017-03-03
$300.00     2017-04-01  2017-03-22
$40         2017-04-12
```

Table Bar becomes:

```
A          B
Date       Total
2017-02-30 $240
2017-03-15 $300
2017-03-30 $0
2017-04-15 $0
```

When it should be:

```
A          B
Date       Total
2017-02-30 $240
2017-03-15 $300
2017-03-30 $40
2017-04-15 $0
```

Is this an issue with my formula or is this a weird efficiency bug?

I'm using Excel 2013 version 1609 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe SUMIFS calculate the IF statement on the criteria_range based on the position of the cell the formula is in rather than per position - ie, if the formula is in B4, then it evaluates ISBLANK(Foo!D4) and uses that to determine which column to use for the criteria range.  If you make the date in Foo!D4 2017-04-02, the $300 shows up in B4.  The last $40 is still missing, though, because B4 is using column D as criteria_range, thus summing-if based on Foo!D5, which has no value and thus doesn't fit the date range, and B5 is using column C (because Foo!D5 is blank) for dates past 2017-04-15, which doesn't match for Foo!C5.

I was able to make it working using an array formula, which uses the conditional range as expected:

```
=SUM(IF((IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C,Foo!D:D)>=Bar!A4)*(IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C,Foo!D:D)<Bar!A5),Foo!A:A))
```

Since this is an array or CSE formula, you have to close out of the cell by pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter for it to work. That means you'll have to hit F2 or click in the formula bar, paste, and then Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just pasting the text (unless you are copying from a cell that already has it as an array formula).  You will be able to tell because it will show in the formula bar with curly braces around it.

```
{=SUM(IF((IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C,Foo!D:D)>=Bar!A4)*(IF(ISBLANK(Foo!D:D),Foo!C:C,Foo!D:D)<Bar!A5),Foo!A:A))}
```

It does NOT work for you to put the curly braces in yourself. ;-)

The array formula uses * for "AND" and + for "OR" logic - basically, evaluates to 1 if TRUE, 0 if FALSE, so multiply criteria if you require both (1*0 is 0, 1*1 is 1), add criteria if you only need one of them to be true (1+0 is 1, 1+1 is 2 which qualifies).

The middle IF functions determine the array to be compared to each of the conditions.  The array formula determines the result at each position x, multiplies by the other criteria, and returns the value to the first IF function as the result of the logical_test.

The first IF function then creates an array based on these results: IF the criteria evaluate to TRUE at position x, then the value in column A at position x gets added to the array.

The SUM then sums the array passed to it by the first IF function.

Comment: I find it odd that the SUMIFS logic works like that. I certainly did not see any reference to the logic behaving that way in the documents I saw but your formula works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I think Excel evaluates the IF statement once and then passes the resulting range to the SUMIF.  If you have a single cell and put =TableName [ColumName] in it, the result is the value of the cell in that column with the same row number as your cell (rather than the entire column), which was what made me realize what was going on after fiddling with your data.  Since it isn't an "array" formula, it processes the range in the logical_test the same way.  So glad my answer helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, array formulas can slow down your workbook if you have hundreds of them and can be a little hard to write, so a simpler method might be to turn your data on Foo! into a table and put

```
=IF(ISBLANK([@[Paid]]),[Due],[Paid])
```

in column E (table should extend to include this column) and use TableName[columnE'sHeaderName] as the range in your SUMIF on Bar!.

Don't want to see this column or worry about someone changing it?  Just hide the column. ;-)

This would also allow you to use the same "which date" logic other places in your wookbook without calculating it every time or using a whole bunch of array formulas.  It would also allow you to use the data on Foo! as the source for a pivot table in which you wanted to use this calculated date instead of always the Due date or always the Paid date.

Don't know why I didn't think of this to start with since I use it all the time...